# Azure DevOps scheduled release with approvals

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a question concerning a release pipeline with both a schedule, as well as approvals.

Right now, the pipeline flows as follows:

1. A new build is triggered by a merge on our master branch
2. From the new build, a new release is automatically created
3. The schedule of this release is to wait until Saturday morning 3 AM to fire
4. On 3 AM, it sends approval requests for the people in the pipeline
5. After approval, the release happens

Steps 3, 4 and 5 are in the wrong order for our process. What it actually should do is:

3. Ask for approval
4. After approval, schedule the build for a release on Saturday 3 AM
5. Initiate the release

I can get there by introducing an empty stage that only handles the approval part, and in a next stage handle the deployment per schedule. But that seems like a workaround for something that should be doable in a better way. So am I missing an option here, or is this the way to do it?

Comment: The introduction of empty stage as you mentioned is the way to implement this with the current available options in release pipelines

Comment: Ok. You can add that as an answer if you want the point to be awarded :)

Answer (score 2):

@ChamindaC is correct. Your solution to have an **Approval Stage** that would precede the **Scheduled stage** is how the ordering of approvals and triggers can be accomplished.

I believe the order of appearance in the per stage **Pre-deployment Conditions** menu is also the order of execution.

---

[image]